# containerPadding prop is not working in react-grid-layout library

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

What I want to do is,

1, users should be able to scroll items horizontally

2, the each item should have margin right/left 16px

3, the padding right/left inside the container should be 16px

So it should have 16px spacing between each item and also the container.

The problem here is that the last item(h) to the container doesn't have any spacing.
[image]

However, it should have `16px` since I have `containerPadding={[16, 24]}` prop.

The first item(a) to the container have 16px padding correctly though.

[image]

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import GridLayout from "react-grid-layout";

import "react-grid-layout/css/styles.css";
import "react-resizable/css/styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const layout = [
    { i: "a", x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
    { i: "b", x: 1, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
    { i: "c", x: 2, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
    { i: "d", x: 3, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
    { i: "e", x: 4, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
    { i: "f", x: 5, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
    { i: "g", x: 6, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
    { i: "h", x: 7, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 }
  ];

  const [lists, setLists] = useState(layout);

  const handleDragStop = (layout, oldItem, newItem) => {
    console.log("layout", layout);
    console.log("oldItem", oldItem);
    console.log("newItem", newItem);

    const sortedLayout = [...layout].sort((a, b) => {
      console.log("a.x", a.x);
      return a.x - b.x;
    });
    sortedLayout.forEach((item, index) => {
      item.x = index;
      item.y = 0;
    });

    setLists(sortedLayout);
  };

  const calculateWidth = (numberOfColumns) => {
    const itemWidth = 150; // Set the width of each item
    const margin = 16;
    const containerPadding = 16;

    return (
      numberOfColumns * itemWidth +
      (numberOfColumns - 1) * margin +
      2 * containerPadding
    );
  };

  const width = calculateWidth(layout.length);
  console.log("width", width);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <GridLayout
          className="layout"
          layout={lists}
          cols={layout.length}
          rowHeight={60}
          width={width}
          margin={[16, 0]}
          containerPadding={[16, 24]}
          onDragStop={handleDragStop}
          maxRows={1}
          compactType="horizontal"
        >
          <div key="a" className="grid-item">
            a
          </div>
          <div key="b" className="grid-item">
            b
          </div>
          <div key="c" className="grid-item">
            c
          </div>
          <div key="d" className="grid-item">
            d
          </div>
          <div key="e" className="grid-item">
            e
          </div>
          <div key="f" className="grid-item">
            f
          </div>
          <div key="g" className="grid-item">
            g
          </div>
          <div key="h" className="grid-item">
            h
          </div>
        </GridLayout>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border: blueviolet 1px solid;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  border: 2px solid #d9d9d9;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.grid-item {
  background: pink;
}

.grid-item:hover {
  top: -1px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px 0px #3e3e3e33;
}
```

[The doc for react-grid-layout props](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout#grid-layout-props)